# Jump in first grade list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

If you want to rearrange the list of questions, for example, and make the last question moves place the question that preceded everything I have done is the value of the key, but it seems to me that I was wrong and the proof you receive this message:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The property 'ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

```
public ActionResult Up(int id , string st)
{
    var qus = db.Qusetions.Find(id);

    if(st == "up")
    {
        if(qus.ID != 1)
        {
            qus.ID = -1;
            var qusup = db.Qusetions.SingleOrDefault(q => q.ID == q.ID - 1);
            if (qusup != null)
            {
                qusup.ID = id;
            }
        }          
    }
    if (st == "down")
    {
        qus.ID = +1;
        var qusup = db.Qusetions.SingleOrDefault(q => q.ID == q.ID + 1);
        if (qusup != null)
        {
            qusup.ID = id;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Qustions", action = "Index", id = id }));
}
```

Comment: Just don't modify a Id column if its your primary key. Add to your entity new column SortIndex which you will use to sort the rows. Then modify this new property as you need.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but how do I enumerate the list by Sort Index

Comment: db.Qusetions.SingleOrDefault(q => q.SortIndex == q.SortIndex - 1). Just introduce another field which will hold current sort order. You cannot modify Id values of your primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't use the primary key `Id` for this purpose. It's much better to add a property to your `Question` that will serve for the single purpose of sorting the questions.

```
public class Qusetion
{
    // ...
    public int SortIndex {get; set;}
    // ...
}
```

Your controller action would be something like this:

```
public ActionResult ChangeSortIndex(int id , string st)
{
    var qus = db.Qusetions.Find(id);

    if(qus != null)
    {
        switch(st)
        {
            case "up":
                qus.SortIndex++;
                break;

            case "down":
                qus.SortIndex--;
                break;
        } 

        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Qusetions", action = "Index", id = id }));
}
```

And when you display your questions you have to sort them:

```
var questions = db.Qusetions.OrderBy(x => x.SortIndex)
```

Also note that the `SortIndex` is updated in a really simple way (++ and --) and you will have to update several indexes to achieve the desired sorting. I guess that for small lists this can work.

You could use something more elaborate like : [What's the best way to manage list item sort order](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/153692/whats-the-best-way-to-manage-list-item-sort-order-with-drag-drop-ui)

Note: In your code, is it a typo or do you really spell it: **Quse**tion  ?

Comment: Very cool to explain the dilemma faced even opened new horizons for me and for actually spell is wrong preceded by hundreds of functions and did not allow me to modify it will be in the final revision, God willing. Greetings to you, O creator